# Конвертировать Prototype в jQuery

Tags: jquery

Друзья, помогите, пожалуйста, написать вот это

```
 <script>
   var select = document.querySelector('.select');
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.writetous__item'),           function (ths)
        {
        ths.onclick = function ()
            {
            select.value = this.children[0].innerHTML;
            }
        });
 </script>
```

на jQuery.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Выбрать элементы](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/) / [Виды селекторов](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
2. [Подписаться на событие](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
3. [Получить html](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
4. [Работа со значением input/select/textarea](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
5. [DOMReady](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

---

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $select = $('.select:first');

    // Вариант №1
    $('.writetous__item').on('click', function () {
        var html = $(this).children().first().html();
        $select.val(html);
    });

    // Вариант №2: если контент обновляется динамически
    $(document).on('click', '.writetous__item', function () {
        var html = $(this).children().first().html();
        $select.val(html);
    });
});
```

Comment: Мне помогли с этим вот тут http://javascript.ru/forum/dom-window/49615-selected-pri-klike-na-ssylku.html, но, к сожалению, у меня нет в проекте прототипа, вот хотел конвертировать.

Comment: У вас код написан на чистом JS, никакой другой библиотеки в нем не используется, просто он немного не кросбраузерно.

Comment: Ну а такое провернуть на jQuery можно?

Comment: Я Вам дал исчерпывающий ответ, как и вариант снизу, они оба работают на Вашем же примере http://jsbin.com/durebovewuyo/1/edit, остальное зависит от расположения Ваших рук.

Comment: @Pavel_G, может вы хотели сделать что-то вроде [своего метода или плагина][1]?

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ddsp8m5k/

Answer (score 1):

```
var select = $('.select');
$('.writetous__item').click(function() {
    select.val(this.children[0].innerHTML;);
});
```

Comment: К сожалению, вариант не работает, я описывал проблему тут http://javascript.ru/forum/dom-window/49615-selected-pri-klike-na-ssylku.html. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, очень надо.